# ModelMapper get confuse on different properties

Tags: java, modelmapper

I have a `Student` object extending `Person` object.

```
public abstract class Person implements IIdentifiable {
    private String contactNumber;
    // other properties
    public String getContactNumber() {
        return contactNumber;
    }

    public void setContactNumber(String contactNumber) {
        this.contactNumber = contactNumber;
    }
}

public class Student extends Person {
    private String studentNumber;
    //Other properties
    public String getStudentNumber() {
        return studentNumber;
    }

    public void setStudentNumber(String studentNumber) {
        this.studentNumber = studentNumber;
    }
}
```

Student has a property `studentNumber` and person has a property `contactNumber`. When I map Student object to `StudentDto` it get confused on given properties.

```
public class StudentDto{
    private String studentNumber;
    public String getStudentNumber() {
        return studentNumber;
    }

    public void setStudentNumber(String studentNumber) {
        this.studentNumber = studentNumber;
    }
}
```

This happens on certain occations only. I'm wondering what would be the reason

```
1) The destination property com.cinglevue.veip.web.dto.timetable.StudentDto.setStudentNumber() matches multiple source property hierarchies:
com.cinglevue.veip.domain.core.student.StudentProfile.getStudent()/com.cinglevue.veip.domain.core.Person.getContactNumber()
com.cinglevue.veip.domain.core.student.StudentProfile.getStudent()/com.cinglevue.veip.domain.core.Student.getStudentNumber()
```

Comment: can you please post your tried code ,as well as Student & Person class

Comment: Sure. I  update the post

Comment: Could you post your ModelMapper configuration and map? Or simply the code case map when the error is happen.

Answer (score 5):

**1.**
You can change the `MatchingStrategies`, using :

```
modelMapper.getConfiguration().setMatchingStrategy(MatchingStrategies.STRICT);
```

PS: modelmapper uses `MatchingStrategies.STANDARD` implicitly

But it requires that property name tokens on the source and destination side match each other precisely.

**2.**
Tell to the ModelMapper to ignore the mapping when it finds multiple source property hierarchies:

```
modelMapper.getConfiguration().setAmbiguityIgnored(true);
```

Comment: I cannot remember why I had this problem now. Anyway someone might benefit. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

it's so long time since you asked. Because of no answer here, I show you my solution that works well for me.

That issue is caused by destination properties name let ModelMapper be confused.
So, to resolve that, we need to do 2 steps.
1. Say ModelMapper ignore something that may be confusing.
2. Specify indicate mapping for confused properties.

Detail code is here:

```
ModelMapper modelMapper = new ModelMapper();

modelMapper.getConfiguration().setAmbiguityIgnored(true);

modelMapper.createTypeMap(Student.class, StudentDto.class)
    .addMapping(Student::getStudentNumber, StudentDto::setStudentNumber);
```

Comment: yes, I cannot remember why I had this problem now. Anyway someone might benefit. Thanks

Comment: How do you do that with nested objects?